# Set QDoubleSpinBox value to an empty string, when not enabled

Tags: python, pyqt, qdoublespinbox

If I have a QDoubleSpinBox and have a method available called `setEnabled` which takes a boolean value. If this value is set to False, the QDoubleSpinBox will appear greyed, showing the number inside the Spin Button, but not allowing the user to type anything or interact with it. I would like a slight modification, such that when the QDoubleSpinBox is not enabled, I would like the Spin Button value to be set to an empty string or not rendered, and remove any previous value from being shown.

Comment: An empty string can be set by means of the [setSpecialValueText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#specialValueText-prop) method.

Comment: @Xukrao How could I create an event such that when the QSpinBox is not enabled, it will automatically set the value to an empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to show and hide the [`QLineEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#lineEdit) of the [`QDoubleSpinBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) if the [`QDoubleSpinBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) is enabled or disabled, respectively. To detect the change of state of the enabled property, you must override the [`changeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent) method and verify the [`QEvent::EnabledChange`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum) event:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class DoubleSpinBox(QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox):
    def changeEvent(self, e):
        if e.type() == QtCore.QEvent.EnabledChange:
            self.lineEdit().setVisible(self.isEnabled())
        return super().changeEvent(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("enabled/disabled")
    spinbox = DoubleSpinBox()
    radiobutton.toggled.connect(spinbox.setDisabled)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(radiobutton)
    lay.addWidget(spinbox)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't want to be a heckler, but shouldn't it be the opposite? Enable it when checked, disabled when unchecked.

Comment: @kalzso That is a matter of UIX which is irrelevant in this case since the question is not about that subject